# sublime: pink "}" triggered by {{ }}

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3

When I'm editing a html file with some javascript code the last brace is marked pink whenever double braces are used.

Example:

```
<script type=text/javascript>

function test(){
  $SCRIPT_ROOT={{request.script_root|tojson|safe}}
} //this brace is getting an annyoingly pink background

</script>
```

I'm obviously new to Sublime and haven't installed any addditional plugins.

Comment: What is with that syntax? Seems rather strange. Guessing that is some sort of other framework that replaces it? Maybe Flask? Maybe you need to add the packages to support it in the IDE>

Comment: yes, using flask (and so some jinja2 - which appears to be the problematic part). Neither jinja2 extension throuhg the package installation nore the one from github https://github.com/antal-bukos/sublimetext3_jinja2_syntax did any improvement.

Comment: funny thing: even without any additional plugin sublime text correctly identified the opening "{" and marked it by underlining.. not keeping it from painting it pink though.

Comment: I am facing the same issue almost 2 years later. If you found a solution, let me know.